# how can remove decimal place after value in C#?

Tags: string, c#-4.0, decimal

Let I have decimal value of `14.8447` and I need this value `8447` in string.

Can any one find any way for me using window Forms C#.

Comment: oded, I solved it with the below code of @Uwe-Keim
thanks

Comment: That wasn't the point of my question. We expect people to make an effort before asking and show their effort as part of the question.

Comment: ok, sorry for that but it was old post and i don't remind what i tried but next time sure i will post my code as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
decimal d = 14.8447m;
string s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string t = s.Substring( s.IndexOf('.')+1);
```

(Although I think my code is a bit of a hack)

To make it a little bit more error-proof, you could write:

```
decimal d = 14.8447m;
string s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int index = s.IndexOf('.');
string t = index >= 0 && index + 1 < s.Length
       ? s.Substring(index + 1)
       : string.Empty;
```

This works well with e.g. the following numbers:

```
decimal d = 14m; // Returning empty string.
decimal d = .3m; // Returning "3".
```

Here is a [short online version at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/v1IyF).

Comment: It would be easiest to manipulate the string anyway. I wouldn't say it is a "hack".

Answer (score 0):

string.Format("{0:0.0000}", 14.8447m).Split(',', '.').Last()

Answer (score 0):

Could be so:

```
decimal Numero = 8.24M;
string r = (Numero - Math.Floor(Numero)).ToString().Replace("0.", "");
```

Easy I guess;